# Отследить НГ в php

Tags: дата, php

Доброго всем здравия после НГ праздников.
Возникла мысль, автоматизировать функционал.
Показывать определённые блоки в период НГ праздников.
Пошёл через:

---

```
$curent_date=date("d.m.y");
$ng_start_date_bef="20.12.".date("y"); // 20 декабря текущего года
$ng_start_date_aft="20.12.".date("y");
date_modify($ng_start_date_aft, "-1 year");  // это дата для, после того как прошёл НГ, т.е. прошлогодний год.
.... // и тут я запутался... ведь до НГ надо чтобы дата до НГ была = "текущему году", а после стала "текущий-1"!
$ng_end_date="20.01.".date("y"); //20 января, завершение праздников.
//А после новогодняя дата, до НГ должна была становиться "текущий год+1", а после НГ, соответственно дата="текущий"...
```

---

Я пришёл к выводу, что если бы это было посередине года, то нет проблем отследить промежуток даты...
А тут я вижу простым решением не обойтись. Или я не прав?

Comment: иногда задачу нужно вывернуть "на изнанку". Представьте, что задача звучит так "Показывать определенный блок, но только не в период НГ". Тогда диапазон будет от 20янв до 20 дек, в пределах одного календарного года. Когда все заработает, просто сделайте инверсию условия вывода.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот наливал чай и та же идея, ну практически та же, стукнула тёплым течением мыслей в мою и без этого горячую голову...  
Можно мерить двумя периодами: от 20.12 до 31.12 текущего, и все, а потом вторым после НГ, с 01.01, до 20.01 тоже текущего!  
Просто будет 2 периода, 2 условия.
Хотя ещё подумаю, Ваш вариант интереснее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не писал код, так как считаю, что это примитивный код и его можно написать за пару минут. Но посмотрев на код [@alexsis20102](/users/2664/alexsis20102), я понял, почему недолюбливают php программистов.

Вот код, с всей обвязкой он сильно меньше вышеприведенного.

```
<?php

//$cd = strtotime('2015-02-20'); // текущая дата для ручного ввода
$cd = date("y-m-d"); // просто текущая дата

$ng_stop=strtotime(date("y-01-20")); // дата, когда заканчиваются НГ праздники
$ng_start=strtotime(date("y-12-20")); // дата, когда начинаются праздники

if ($ng_start >= $cd and $cd > $ng_stop) { // собственно условие
    echo "не НГ\n";
} else {
    echo "а это НГ\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: А я недолюбливаю не php-программеров, а сам php.
И хотя бы за это: www.icar-soft.ru/development/simple_math.php

Answer (score 0):

задачу решить очень просто с помощью следующих манипуляций

```
$dateson = "20.12.2014"; //Дата начала показа
$datefinish =  date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateson)+60*60*24*30);// Дата окончания в примере к дате начала прибавляем 30 дней
//Пишем условие показа блока
if(date('Y-m-d') < $datefinish) // Тут проверяем если текущая дата меньше финишной то показываем блок
{
 //код нужного бока
}
```

Если нужно динамическое определения нового или старого года то можно придумать условие для него но проще стартовую дату вынести в файл конфигурации и в ручную ее обновлять.

условие для автоматического определения года

```
$year = date('Y-m-d'); 
$yearon =  date("Y",strtotime($year)-60*60*24*30);
if($yearon != date('Y'))
{
   // Тут мы определили что если от текущий даты отнять 30 дней то год не равен текущему а это означает что он меньше можно полученое значение $yearon подставить в дату начала показа болка

}
```

Таким образом окончательная версия скрипта может выглядеть так

```
$year = date('Y-m-d'); 
$yearon =  date("Y",strtotime($year)-60*60*24*30);
if($yearon != date('Y'))
{
   $god = $yearon;
}
else
{
   $god = date('Y');
}

 $dateson = "20.12.".$god; //Дата начала показа
$datefinish =  date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateson)+60*60*24*30);// Дата окончания в примере к дате начала прибавляем 30 дней
//Пишем условие показа блока
if(date('Y-m-d') < $datefinish) // Тут проверяем если текущая дата меньше финишной то показываем блок
{
 //код нужного бока
}
```

Comment: о, ещё дату в конфиг выносить. Пишите так дальше. Посмотрите мое решение. оно сильно проще.

Comment: Ну если твой вариант проще то напиши ответ с примером своего кода.

Comment: @alexsis20102 "но проще стартовую дату вынести в файл конфигурации и в ручную ее обновлять."
Издеваетесь? Я и так вручную обновляю это в массиве JS уже лет 8. Каждый НГ и День Победы тоже. Поэтому и решил автоматизировать это дело.  
Первый вариант у вас, мне кажется, хотя бы имеет право на существование. Он тоже вариант от кода @KoVadim

Comment: to @alexsis20102, Я сильно не просил пример пример кода, а @KoVadim дал хорошую, простую, рабочую идею.  
О чём я и написал в комментарии.  
А с кодом я справлюсь

Comment: С кодом не справился... Видать, надо бросать одно из многих: или пить, или работать, или программировать...  
(Всё так же, но не работает!)
    
    $curent_date=date("d.m.y");
    $ng_start_date="20.12.".date("y");
    $ng_end_date="20.01.".date("y");
    if ( strtotime($curent_date) < strtotime($ng_start_date) and strtotime($curent_date) > strtotime($ng_end_date))
    {
     print "Не НГ";
    }
    else
    {
 print "<img src='".$http_adr."/images/ng.png' style='position:absolute; top:36px; left:680px; z-index:40;'>";
    }

Comment:  strtotime($curent_date) < strtotime($ng_start_date) and strtotime($curent_date) > strtotime($ng_end_date) в первом условии исходя из примера должно быть больше или равно. И все же мой код для меня понятнее и проще